# Просклоняйте словосочетания

Tags: склонение

542 обращения, 387 мониторов......

Comment: Здесь не выполняют за школьников задания, дайте свой вариант, мы оценим,укажем ошибки.

Answer (score 3):

Надо открыть учебник 6 класса, там есть замечательная табличка.